# Why are there different RDDs and what are their respective purposes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

There are a lot of RDDs in Spark; from the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html):

- AsyncRDDActions
- CoGroupedRDD
- DoubleRDDFunctions
- HadoopRDD
- JdbcRDD
- NewHadoopRDD
- OrderedRDDFunctions
- PairRDDFunctions
- PartitionPruningRDD
- RDD
- SequenceFileRDDFunctions
- ShuffledRDD
- UnionRDD

and I do not understand what they are supposed to be.

Additionally I noticed that there are

- `ParallelCollectionRDD`
- `MapPartitionsRDD`

which are not listed though they appear very often in my spark-shell as objects.

#### Question

Why are there different RDDs and what are their respective purposes?

#### What I understood so far

I understood from tutorials and books (e.g. "Learning Spark") that there are two types of operations on RDDs: Those for RDDs which have pairs `(x, y)` and all the other operations. So I would expect to have class `RDD` and `PairRDD` and that's it.

#### What I suspect

I suspect that I got it partly wrong and what is actually the case is that a lot of RDD classes could be just one RDD class - but that would make things less tidy. So instead, the developers decided to put different methods into different classes and in order to provide those to any RDD class type, they use `implicit` to coerce between the class types. I suspect that due to the fact that many of the RDD class types end with "Functions" or "Actions" and text in the respective scaladocs sound like this.

Additionally I suspect that some of the RDD classes still are not like that, but have some more in-depth meaning (e.g. `ShuffledRDD`).

However - I am not sure about any of this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all roughly a half of the listed classes don't extend RDD but are type classes designed to augment RDD with different methods specific to the stored type.

One common example is `RDD[(T, U)]`, commonly known as `PairRDD`, which is enriched by methods provided by `PairRDDFunctions` like `combineByKeyWithClassTag` which is a basic building block for all `byKey` transformations. It is worth nothing that there is no such class as `PairRDD` or `PairwiseRDD` and these names are purely informal.

There are also a few commonly used subclasses of the `RDD` which are not a part of the public API and such are not listed above. Some examples worth mentioning are `ParallelCollectionRDD` and `MapPartitionsRDD`.

`RDD` is an abstract class which doesn't implement two important methods:

- `compute` which computes result for a given partition
- `getPartitions` which return a sequence of partitions for a given `RDD`

In general there are two reasons to subclass RDD;

- create a class representing input source (e.g `ParallelCollectionRDD`, `JdbcRDD`)
- create an `RDD` which provides non standard transformations

So to **summarize**:

- `RDD` class provides a minimal interface for `RDDs`.
- subclasses of `RDD` provide internal logic required for actual computations based on external sources and / or parent `RDDs`. These are either private or part of the developer API and, excluding debug strings or Spark UI, are not exposed directly to the final user.
- type classes provide additional methods based on the type of the values which are stored in the `RDD` and not dependent on how it has been created.

Comment: Ok, but what is the purpose of not extending, but implicit conversions - that which I wrote? What is the point of "representing input source" - afterall `ParallelCollectionRDD` isn't even public api? I appreciate your information - I learned something - but so far I don't feel my question has been answered.

Comment: It is quite simple there is completely different processing logic for accessing external database, converting local collection, or using Hadoop Input sources. None of these classes is designed for public / non dev usage (they are either private or a part of the developer API) and are never exposed in a typical program.

Comment: Fair enough, but there is (hopefully) still a logic behind it. It might be useful when debugging. For example if `ShuffledRDD` were to always turns up right after a shuffle - that were to tell me something pretty useful.